# output byte value in assembler

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm a bit ashamed about asking this, but how do i output the value of a byte in assembler?
Suppose I have the number 62 in the AL register. I'm targeting an 8086. There seem to be available only interrupts that output it's ascii value.

**Edit:** Thank you Nick D, that was what i was looking for. To answer a couple of questions, i'm actually using an emulator, emu8086. The code will be used in a tiny application in a factory that uses outdated equipment (i.e. it's a secret).

The solution, using Nick D's idea, looks somewhat like this:

```
compare number, 99
jump if greater to over99Label
compare number, 9
jump if greater to between9and99Label

;if jumps failed, number has one digit
printdigit(number)

between9and99Label:
divide the number by 10
printascii(quotient)
printascii(modulus)
jump to the end

over99Label:
divide the number by 100
printascii(quotient)
store the modulus in the place that between9and99Label sees as input
jump to between9and99Label

the end:
return
```

and it works fine for unsigned bytes :)

Comment: Can you give us some more information about your environment?  Is this an emulator or are you really writing an 8086 assembly program?  If it's a real program, what operating system services do you have access to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// pseudocode for values < 100
printAscii (AL div 10) + 48
printAscii (AL mod 10) + 48
```

Convert the value to a string representation and print it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an assembler at the momment to check it, and syntax will vary anyway depending on what assembler you are using, but this should still convey the idea.

```
FOUR_BITS:
.db '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'

; If ebx need to be preserved do so
push  ebx

; Get the top four bits of al
mov   bl, al
shl   bl, 4

; Convert that into the ASCII hex representation
mov   bl, [FOUR_BITS + bl]

; Use that value as a parameter to your printing routine
push  bl
call  printAscii
pop   bl

; Get the bottom four bits of al
mov   bl, al
and   bl, 0xF

; Convert that into the ASCII hex representation
mov   bl, [FOUR_BITS + bl]

; Use that value as a parameter to your printing routine
push  bl
call  printAscii
pop   bl
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work. suppose i want to print the number 123?

Comment: This prints out the value of the AL register in hexadecimal (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). The decimal number 123 is equivalent to the hexadecimal number 7B (aka 0x7B), which is what this code is intended to produce.

Comment: ok, thumbs up then, but i wanted a decimal representation, that's why i dismissed your code when i saw you're breaking the byte and only printing two characters.